# Modify Stylesheet properties in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

I am preloading stylesheets inside this method OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext) in MVC, this is just to make sure that this is done before the actionResult is called when loading the page, and this works fine, my issue is now i want to modify the style sheet background-image property in a class called logo and before the tag is built(code below) and added to the head section in the DOM, I'm wondering if there isn't a way to read(StreamReader?/StreamWriter?) the css file and modify it and save it before the tag is built or something like that, btw Im getting the css file from the server.

```
foreach (string file in filepath)
{
    if (Path.GetExtension(file).ToLower() == ".css")
    {
        TagBuilder link = new TagBuilder("link");
        link.Attributes["rel"] = "stylesheet";
        link.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
        link.Attributes["href"] = urlHelper.Content(
            string.Format("~/Content/themes/Theme{0}/{1}",
                setting.ThemeId, Path.GetFileName(file)));

        resources.Add(MvcHtmlString.Create(link.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just load another style sheet after this one and amend class style that way, infact that's exactly how I do this for my white label solution.

Comment: I also thought of that, dnt u know how would I change stylesheet property?

Comment: Add an asp.net handler that dynamically creates a stylesheet, so you can then link it in browser and use values on querystring to change the content dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Can´t you use LESS to dinamicaly create your css?

http://www.dotlesscss.org/

http://karlmendes.com/2010/07/using-less-css-for-net-with-asp-net-mvc-2/

Maybe it will make things easier for you...